# Python turtle graphics eating a lot of memory

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I started messing around with python turtle graphics and it seems that at a certain point in my program it starts to take up a lot of memory in my task manager (around 2gb) and become a bit laggy. I'm assuming its must be the turtles so I tried to use the turtle.clearscreen() midway through the program and I saw that it still was sucking up the same amount of memory or was still increasing in size so i'm assuming its not actually deleting the turtles.

The only fix seems to be to exit the python turtle graphics completely which ends up ending the program however i still want the program to continue. Is anyone aware of a solution for this?

Comment: Provide your source code if you want someone to look for your memory problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Is there any solution to this? In my game app, I have created 3 lives. As long as a life is consumed in a short period of the game, the game progresses to next life as intended. However, if I manage to run the game for long with one life, it does not move to next life when the current life ends. In task manager I see pycharm (running only the turtle project) progressively consuming almost 2 GB in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the amount of memory you have or close unnecessary tasks. I'm not sure if there is a way to decrease the ram turtle itself uses, so use these methods as a starting base.